# NULL returned on simple PDO statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm stuck here with this seemly simple piece of PDO, I'm more than likely missing the smallest of things, or have a syntax issue that is just out of my eyesight, but I was hoping I'd be able to get some help here, I've already tried searching around, attempted different things, but can't make much progress.

```
if (empty($_GET['id'])) {
    header('Location: ' . BASE_URL . '/admin-home/list.php');
    die();
}

$page = $db->prepare("
    SELECT id, title, label, body, slug
    FROM pages
    WHERE id=:id
");


$page->execute([':id' => $_GET['id']]);

$page = $page->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

var_dump($page);
```

Running the following will always redirect immediately to the "list.php" page, removing the if statement at the top always displays "NULL"

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, like I said before, I'm probably not noticing the most obvious of things wrong here.

Comment: Do you have PHP 5.4 or higher?

Comment: What is it that you put in the `execute` ? A php array suppose to be like `array(':id' => $_GET['ID'])`.

Comment: execute need array like `$page->execute(array(':id' =>  $_GET['id']));`

Comment: @frz3993 Wrong, if PHP 5.4 or higher that's the correct way to create an array.

Comment: @Daan yes I do
frz3993 & Saty,  I've made ammends now and the output is producing "bool(false)"

Comment: What is the value of `$_GET['id']` ?????

Comment: Thanks @JackJack. Found it in the doc. I'll put the link here[http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the `id` parameter to the page when you access it from your browser. So, if your page is at `http://www.example.com/test.php`, you need to type into your browser `http://www.example.com/test.php?id=123`, where `123` is your ID value.

This is why this is happening:

> Running the following will always redirect immediately to the "list.php" page

Because `$_GET['id']` is empty. Removing this check causes the page to always returns `NULL` because you're passing `null` to be bound to `:id`, which must not return any rows from the DB.

Comment: I feel like an absolute fool for not seeing something so simple, that's done the trick, I'd actually had a typo in the URL, I was heading to ?page=123, instead of ?id=123, thanks so much for that!

Comment: @JackJack Haha! Not a problem, I'm glad I could help!